# Android list view to display different data sets

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there a way to get the `listview` to display `data` provided from another `array` list without having to create a `new adapter` and setting it?

I ask because the way I have it now prevents me from maintaining the scroll position of the list view

Comment: Have you tried changing the data in the existing adapter and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Yes I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() does not work on its own without creating a new adapter for the other array list

Comment: you have to reassigned array list to adapter if you are creating new array list...

Comment: Also you should use setviewtypecount and getviewtype method of baseadapter different view type set

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about different datasets and different display per dataset.

If this is the case, you can use one of few solutions:

1. feel free to use either `RecyclerView` with multiple `ViewHolder` classes for it.
2. Try unifying the dataset representations with a common parent class and use one `Adapter` while overriding the `getViewTypeCount` to return 2 and then inflate different views for each type.
3. Try using [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).